# How to return a date format with PySpark with Databricks

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

The following PySpark code will return the following date format on the field 'mydates'

as yyyy-MM-dd

```
df = sql("select * from mytable where mydates = last_day(add_months(current_date(),-1))")
```

However, I would like the code to return the 'mydates' field with the following format

yyyyMMdd

I tried the following

```
df = sql("select * from mytable where mydates = last_day(add_months(current_date(),'yyyyMMdd'-1))")
```

I didn't get an error with the above, however it didnt' return any results. Whereas the previous code did return results, but with date format on field 'mydates' as yyyy-MM-dd and I would like yyyyMMdd.

Any thoughts?

I have updated this question in line with the suggested answer, however I'm still getting yyyy-MM-dd.

```
%python
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.sql("select * from xxxxx where date_format(mydates, 'yyyyMMdd') = date_format(last_day(add_months(current_date(), -1)), 'yyyyMMdd')")
```

Very strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is my date format in the table. I believe it is same format in your table also.

[image]

No matter what format you check the condition in **where** you need to reformat in **select** clause. Because your format in the table initially itself
in `yyyy-MM-dd`

[image]

So, you need to alter in **select** clause itself.

code:

```
spark.sql("select  date_format(mydates,'yyyyMMdd') as mydates from mytable where mydates =  last_day(add_months(current_date(),-1))").show()

spark.sql("select  date_format(mydates,'yyyyMMdd') as mydates from mytable where  date_format(mydates, 'yyyyMMdd') =  date_format(last_day(add_months(current_date(), -1)), 'yyyyMMdd')").show()
```

One more way of doing is using in-built function in spark `regexp_replace`, that is after getting it from sql query.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
spark.sql("select mydates from mytable").withColumn("dates-reformat", regexp_replace(col('mydates'), '-', '')).show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi @JayashankarGS, thanks for getting in touch. I appreciate you can achieve the results I need when selecting a single column ```spark.sql("select  date_format(mydates,'yyyyMMdd') as mydates from mytable where  date_format(mydates, 'yyyyMMdd') =  date_format(last_day(add_months(current_date(), -1)), 'yyyyMMdd')")```, but how would you include all the fields? The following will include all the fields but doesn't work ```df = spark.sql("select * mytable where date_format(mydates, 'yyyyMMdd') = date_format(last_day(add_months(current_date(), -1)), 'yyyyMMdd')")```. This still gives yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: If you know the column name then use my second approach, replacing the substring after query.

Answer (score 0):

To modify the date format in the SQL query, you can use the date_format function provided by Spark SQL. Here's an example of how you can modify the code to achieve the desired date format:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.sql("select * from mytable where date_format(mydates, 'yyyyMMdd') = date_format(last_day(add_months(current_date(), -1)), 'yyyyMMdd')")
```

In this modified code, the `date_format` function is used to format both the `mydates` field and the result of `last_day(add_months(current_date(), -1))` to the `'yyyyMMdd'` format. This allows you to compare the two dates in the desired format.

Make sure to import the necessary functions (`date_format`) and create a `SparkSession` before running the code.

By using this modified code, the query will filter the `mytable` dataframe to only include rows where the `mydates` field matches the `yyyyMMdd` format of the last day of the previous month.

Please note that you need to have the correct column name (`mydates`) in the `select` clause of the query, and adjust the code according to your specific use case and column names.

Comment: Hi @gaetano, thanks for getting in touch. I updated my question with your suggested answer, however as I mentioned I'm still not getting any results

Comment: Hi @gaetano, I've just updated the question again.

Comment: ok, I realised I didn't use @gaetano's suggestion is he planned. I have updated the question showing that I used the suggestion exactly as described but still not getting any results